# I can't locate successfully installed android studio in windows 10

Tags: flutter, android-studio, windows-10, android-emulator

I have installed android studio and emulator in my windows 10. Created a flutter app and run on emulator. Then closed the project, and closed android studio And shutdown my pc. Everything happened smoothly with no errors. But when I restarted my pc two days after. I searched for android studio in windows search, there is no search result for that. Then I saw all of my apps, android studio is not there. Then saw this directory.

> C:\Users\hayee\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

There is no exe or other file to launch android studio. I also have project files that I had created. Then I saw in uninstall programs I found there. Here is screenshot.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MveBD.png)

Also there is no solution on internet.

Answer (score 5):

I found studio64.exe in following directory.

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin

Here I can launch android studio by double clicking studio64.exe file.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut for android studio could be in this location :

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio

studio64.exe